# Links to Q&A proposals don't always lead to alive proposals

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, advertising

Looking on serverfault.com, I found this Q&A ad:

---

[image: DotNetNuke Q&A]

---

But when I clicked it, it took me to [this page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15362/dotnetnuke?commit=1), indicating the Q&A proposal is dead. Either that's a very unlucky race condition, or the system doesn't filter out dead proposals.

Comment: Does anyone have the video of the autopsy?

Comment: BTW that's Server Fault screen, not Super User.

Comment: @Sathya Yup, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed now. We had forgotten to weed out proposals that were *deleted*, but never *closed*.